# javascript functions not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am working on a simple calculator in javascript, and have made a table for the buttons and everything, but when I test out the functions, it either returns, NaN or undefined. I am not completely finished, as I have not added anything other than + and = functions, as well as the numbers, and the equals function is just a test right now. Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<script> 
var answers = new Array();
var ar = 0;
var array = new Array();
var operation = 5;
var ans;
String(document.getElementById("answer")).value;
function one(x){
String(array[ar]);
array[ar] = array[ar] + x;
parseFloat(array[ar]);
return document.getElementById("answer").value = document.getElementById("answer").value + x;
}
function add(){
if(ar > 0){
answers[ar] = array[ar] + array[ar-1];
return document.getElementById("answer").value = document.getElementById("answer").value + "+";
ar = ar+1;
}
else {
answers[ar] = array[ar];
return document.getElementById("answer").value = document.getElementById("answer").value + "+";
ar = ar+1;
}
}
function answr(){
alert(answers[ar])

}
</script>
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this?: String(document.getElementById("answer")).value; .. or this: String(array[ar]);

Comment: @lombausch I am trying to make it so when they press the number button on the calculator, it will add the number like a string such as instead of adding 1 + 1 to get 2, it will get 11, then I convert 11 back to a number instead of a string.

Comment: 1.) you have to assign the result of the operation to some variable. 2.) String(document.getEl..) will only stringify the name of the element

Answer (score 0):

You should put `ar = ar + 1` BEFORE the `return` statement, as the function ends when you call `return`.

```
if(ar > 0){
    answers[ar] = array[ar] + array[ar-1];
    ar = ar+1;
    return document.getElementById("answer").value = document.getElementById("answer").value + "+";
```

And so.